# Qt redesign TabBar

Tags: c++, qt

So I have my Qt project (it's code editor)
and I want to redesign Tab Bar. I used following code:

**header**

```
#ifndef TABS
#define TABS

#include <QTabBar>

class Tabs : public QTabBar
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Tabs(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

#endif // TABS
```

.cpp

```
#include "tabs.h"
#include <QDebug>

Tabs::Tabs(QWidget *parent)
    : QTabBar(parent)
{
    qDebug() << parent->metaObject()->className();
}

void Tabs::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    for(int index = 0; index < count(); index++ )
    {
        qDebug() << index;
    }
}
```

(qDebug for testing)

Am I doing good or something is wrong with code?
Please help.

Comment: Do you actually have an issue? Did it not work?

Comment: Yup. It doesn't work for me. In "MainWindow" constructor (which is main form in fact) i have this line:

new Tabs(this);

Comment: @PawełMiczka What does not work for you? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code you have then I think you can't see the your custom tab widget becuase you overridden the `paintEvent( ... )` function but did nothing there:

```
void Tabs::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* aEvent )
{
    for(int index = 0; index < count(); ++index )
    {
        qDebug() << index;
    }
}
```

You should call the base class' implementation or do something in it to make some visible results.